# ubuntu 18.04 doesn't detect my second monitor. Could someone help me with this?

Tags: ubuntu, multiple-monitors

I am trying to add a second monitor to my Lenovo laptop through HDMI. But, it just doesn't detect the second one at all.

Here is the output from `xrandr`:

```
xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default
Screen 0: minimum 1920 x 1080, current 1920 x 1080, maximum 1920 x 1080
default connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 0mm x 0mm
   1920x1080     77.00*
```

Here is the output from `inxi -Gxx`:

```
Graphics:  Card: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD/ATI] Picasso
           bus-ID: 03:00.0 chip-ID: 1002:15d8
           Display Server: x11 (X.Org 1.20.1 )
           drivers: fbdev,ati (unloaded: modesetting,vesa,radeon)
           Resolution: 1920x1080@77.00hz
           OpenGL: renderer: llvmpipe (LLVM 7.0, 128 bits)
           version: 3.3 Mesa 18.2.8 (compat-v: 3.1) Direct Render: Yes
```

Here is the output from `uname -a`:

```
Linux tommy-lenovo 4.18.0-21-generic #22~18.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Thu May 16 15:07:19 UTC 2019 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Here is the output from `apt-cache show xserver-xorg | grep Version`:

```
Version: 1:7.7+19ubuntu7.1
Version: 1:7.7+19ubuntu7
```

Here is the output from `apt-cache show gdm3 | grep Version`:

```
Version: 3.28.3-0ubuntu18.04.4
Version: 3.28.0-0ubuntu1
```

Here is the screenshot from display option in setting:

[image]

Here is the screenshot from  multimonitors-add-on from tweak.

[image]

I think xrandr failure seems to be the problem. Could somebody help me with this?

Comment: I have exact same problem using Ubuntu 16.0.4 with Radeon RX 570... xrandr doesn't show my displays. Only one display with `Failed to get size of gamma for output default`

Answer (score -1):

This was solved while I was connecting my JBL bluetooth speaker to ubuntu 18.04. At first, my laptop(ubuntu 18.04) didn't recognize JBL speaker, so I googoled about how to fix it. And I found a solution saying that I need to do:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:bluetooth/bluez
sudo apt install bluez
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:bluetooth/bluez
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

I believe that the commands above have upgraded and updated bluetooth driver. And, this process also has solved the dual monitor issues posted in the first place. Well, it took approximately three to four months to get this worked. And finally, gladly, fortunately, it works now. :)

Comment: These commands upgraded everything that could be upgraded in your system (`apt-get update` fetches list of packages, `apt-get upgrade` upgrades already installed packages to latest version). Lesson: if you have computer problems, try current versions first.